# How can I call FB.getLoginStatus on every route change in React JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to be able to redirect to my sign in page if a user's no longer connected via FB. I have pages on my site that require auth and others that do not. I don't want to add logic to all of my main components to handle this if it is not necessary.

This is easy if you only take into account the user logging out of your app, but if the user logs out of FB they are also logged out of your app and these are the ones that need to be trapped.

In v1.0 of the FB API you could subscribe to these events, but that's no longer an option.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { childrenWithProps } from './utils/utils.js';
import FacebookActions from './actions/FacebookActions';
import FacebookStore from './stores/FacebookStore';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getFacebookState();
    }

    getFacebookState() {
        return {
            accessToken: FacebookStore.accessToken,
            loggedIn: FacebookStore.loggedIn,
            userId: FacebookStore.userId,
            status: FacebookStore.status
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        FacebookActions.initFacebook();
        FacebookStore.addChangeListener(this._onFacebookChange());
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        FacebookStore.removeChangeListener(this._onFacebookChange);
    }

    _onFacebookChange() {
        this.setState(this.getFacebookState());
    }

    render() {
        var { status, loggedIn, userId } = this.state,
            children = childrenWithProps(this, { loggedIn, userId });

        return <div>{children}</div>

    }

}

App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App
```

**FacebookActions.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from './../AppDispatcher.js';
import AppConstants from './../constants/AppConstants.js';

const FacebookActions = {

    initFacebook: function() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : AppConstants.FB_APP_ID,
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.5'
            });

            // after initialization, get the login status
            FacebookActions.getLoginStatus();
        },

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    },

    getLoginStatus: function() {
        window.FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: AppConstants.FACEBOOK_INITIALIZED,
                data: response
            })
        });
    },

    login: () => {
        window.FB.login((response) => {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                    actionType: AppConstants.FACEBOOK_LOGGED_IN,
                    data: response
                })
            }
        });
    },

    logout: () => {
        window.FB.logout((response) => {
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: AppConstants.FACEBOOK_LOGGED_OUT,
                data: response
            })
        })
    },

    getFacebookProfilePicture: (userId) => {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: AppConstants.FACEBOOK_GETTING_PICTURE,
            data: null
        })

        window.FB.api(`/${userId}/picture?type=large`, (response) => {
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: AppConstants.FACEBOOK_RECEIVED_PICTURE,
                data: response
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = FacebookActions;
```

**FacebookStore.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from './../AppDispatcher.js';
import AppConstants from './../constants/AppConstants.js';
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';

const FACEBOOK_CHANGE_EVENT = 'FACEBOOK_CHANGE_EVENT';

class FacebookStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.facebookAuthData = {};
        this.faebookPictureData = {};
    }

    setFacebookAuthData(data) {
        this.facebookAuthData = data;
        this.emitChange();
    }

    get status() {
        if (!this.facebookAuthData) {
            return 'unknown';
        }

        return this.facebookAuthData.status;
    }

    get loggedIn() {
        if (!this.facebookAuthData) {
            return;
        }

        return this.facebookAuthData.status == 'connected';
    }

    get userId() {
        if (!this.facebookAuthData || !this.facebookAuthData.authResponse) {
            return;
        }

        return this.facebookAuthData.authResponse.userID;
    }

    get accessToken() {
        if (!this.facebookAuthData || !this.facebookAuthData.authResponse) {
            return;
        }

        return this.facebookAuthData.authResponse.accessToken;
    }

    get facebookPictureUrl() {
        if (!this.facebookPictureData || !this.facebookPictureData.url) {
            return;
        }

        return this.facebookPictureData.url;
    }

    setFacebookPictureData(type, data) {
        this.facebookPictureStatus = type;

        if (data) {
            this.facebookPictureData = data.data
        } else {
            this.facebookPictureData = {};
        }

        this.emitChange();
    }

    emitChange() {
        this.emit(FACEBOOK_CHANGE_EVENT);
    }

    addChangeListener(callback) {
        this.on(FACEBOOK_CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

    removeChangeListener(callback) {
        this.removeListener(FACEBOOK_CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }
}

// initialize the store as a singleton
const facebookStore = new FacebookStore();

facebookStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register((action) => {
    if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_INITIALIZED) {
        facebookStore.setFacebookAuthData(action.data);
    }

    if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_LOGGED_IN) {
        facebookStore.setFacebookAuthData(action.data);
    }

    if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_LOGGED_OUT) {
        facebookStore.setFacebookAuthData(action.data);
    }

    if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_GETTING_PICTURE) {
        facebookStore.setFacebookPictureData(action.actionType, action.data)
    }

    if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_RECEIVED_PICTURE) {
        facebookStore.setFacebookPictureData(action.actionType, action.data)
    }
})

module.exports = facebookStore;
```

**Some sub-component view...**

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import FacebookActions from './../../../actions/FacebookActions';

class MyPrivatePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        /* 
           THIS CAN'T BE CALLED LIKE THIS
           BECAUSE IT WAS ALSO CALLED IN App.jsx
           AND ALSO BECAUSE window.FB MAY NOT BE
           INITIALiZED YET
        */
        FacebookActions.getLoginStatus();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>If you are seeing this you must be logged in!</div>
        )

    }

}

export default MyPrivatePage
```

This is mainly from https://github.com/subyraman/react-flux-facebook-api-example/blob/master/src/js/components/Main.js

I'm just trying to get it to fully work with my use case. There are no good examples of how to do this out there. Which is really quite strange since React is from FB. There should be tons of examples of this.

**React Versions:**

```
"react": "^0.14.5",
"react-dom": "^0.14.5",
"react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5"
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE ! ! !**

So I decided to add 'fbInitialized' in the FacebookStore when FB is initialized:

```
if (action.actionType == AppConstants.FACEBOOK_INITIALIZED) {
    facebookStore.fbInitialized = true;
    facebookStore.setFacebookAuthData(action.data);
}
```

Then I set the state variable as the same and then access in my Component view files:

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import FacebookActions from './../../../actions/FacebookActions';

class MyPrivatePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggedIn:   false,
            userId:     ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if( FacebookStore.fbInitialized ){
            FacebookActions.getLoginStatus();
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: newProps.loggedIn,
            userId:   newProps.userId
        });
    }

    render() {

        var { loggedIn, userId } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>You { loggedIn ? 'are' : 'are not' } logged in!</div>
        )

    }

}

export default MyPrivatePage
```

**HOWEVER**

It seems like there may be some bug in the FB API in getLoginStatus when running dev on localhost. When I log out of FB on the FB site and then call the function on my site it always returns status: connected until I refresh the page.

**UPDATE II**

To get around the last issue I have found there is a second parameter to 'getLoginStatus' which when set to true will always fetch the real value from FB.

The question still stands though, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.